# Show incoming call notification when the app is terminated or in background in flutter app

Tags: android, ios, flutter, agora

Im using agora to implement a video call in my application, and im using this [flutter_callkit_incoming](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_callkit_incoming) to show this notification.

my flow is this, i get notification from FCM, it shows as normal, when the user open the app through this notification the calling notification pops up then he can answer the call, same flow happens when the app in background or terminated

i need to show the incoming call notification directly instead of the FCM one.

is there anyway to do it ?